# Javascript: parseInt issue when it comes to math operators

Tags: javascript, html-parsing

I have this slider that on 'slide' grabs pricing values (string with euro symbol) from an array, later parsed (parseInt) for the html output. This works fine, on the output i get the number plus the symbol, but when I need to multiply those values (switch month pricing to anual), I loose the output, no numbers or symbol. So I guess the parseInt is working properly without a math operator...? I've serached for similar issues but I couldn't find any solution and it just got me more confused...Can anyone tell what I'm missing? The code:

```
    var priceStarter = [
      '149€',
      '199€',
      '249€',
      '399€',
      '599€',
      '999€',
     'Contact Us',
    ];


    slider.on('slide', function (values, handle) {
      if(jQuery(this).hasClass('active-anual')){
        //ANUAL
           var anualStarter = priceStarter[parseInt(handle)];
           priceValueStarter.html(anualStarter * 10); //ISSUE HERE

      }
      else {
        //MONTHLY
        priceValueStarter.html(priceStarter[parseInt(handle)]); //WORKS

      }
    });

    //TOGGLE ANUAL/MONTHLY
    anual.on('click',function(){
      jQuery(this).toggleClass('active-tab');
     monthly.removeClass('active-tab');
      slider.addClass('active-anual');
    })
    monthly.on('click', function () {
      jQuery(this).toggleClass('active-tab');
     anual.removeClass('active-tab');
      slider.removeClass('active-anual');
    })
  }
```

EDIT:

This `console.log(anualStarter)` gives me the correct value but this `console.log(anualStarter*10)` gives me NaN

EDIT: based on Constantiner's answer, I get the numbers but I still loose the euro symbol and the contact us when using the operator

```
 slider.on('slide', function (values, handle) {
  if (jQuery(this).hasClass('active-anual')) {
    //ANUAL
    var anualStarter = priceStarter[parseInt(handle)];
    priceValueStarter.html(parseInt(anualStarter )*10);


  } else {
    //MONTHLY
    priceValueStarter.html(priceStarter[parseInt(handle)]);    
  }   
})
```

;

Comment: Have you checked the value of `handle` when you parse it? Are you sure there's an element in `priceStrarter` at index `parseInt(handle)`?

Comment: This `console.log(anualStarter)` gives me the correct value but this `console.log(anualStarter*10)` gives me NaN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `priceStarter[parseInt(handle)]` is a string like `"249€"`. So you can't use `anualStarter * 10` (`"249€" * 10`) — it is `NaN`. Try to use `parseInt(anualStarter) * 10` instead.

A little explanation. When you try to use `"249€" * 10` JavaScript engine tries to cast the string "249€" as a Number and doesn't interpret it as integer or something. So your `"249€" * 10` is the same as `Number("249€") * 10` and `Number("249€")` is `NaN`.

I suppose you planned to write some code like the following:

```
slider.on('slide', function (values, handle) {
    if(jQuery(this).hasClass('active-anual')){
      //ANUAL
         var anualStarter = priceStarter[parseInt(handle)];
         priceValueStarter.html(isNaN(parseInt(anualStarter)) ? anualStarter : parseInt(anualStarter) * 10 + "€"); //ISSUE HERE

    }
    else {
      //MONTHLY
      priceValueStarter.html(priceStarter[parseInt(handle)]); //WORKS

    }
  });
```

Comment: it only works when I remove the euro symbol from the array, and when the slider reaches the "Contact US" array position, nothing is shown. But without the operation, works fine...

Comment: I've updated my answer with your code little bit corrected by me.

Comment: I've managed to make this work already and the solution is very similar, it's the same logic, but your code is more elegant, so thank you :)